# Why does P != "P" in my JSON response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, string

**QUESTION:**

For some strange reason, it seems "P" from my JSON is not equal to "P" but "P"=="P" returns true. This makes no sense.

There must be some data type issue somewhere.

How can I make sure `response.charAt(0) == "P"` returns `true` ?

---

**CODE:**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/1/1",
        data: someData,
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log("p" == "P"); //prints false
        console.log("P" == "P"); //prints true
        console.log("RESPONSE: "+response); //prints "Primary"
        console.log("RESPONSE FIRST LETTER: "+response.charAt(0)); //prints P 
        console.log("RESPONSE BOOL P :"+response.charAt(0)=="P"); 
        //
        //false for some reason, should be true 
        //
        if (response.charAt[0] == "P") {
            console.log("1");
            localStorage.setItem("error_msg_local", message);
        } else if (response.charAt[0] == "L") {
            localStorage.setItem("success_msg_local", message);
            console.log("2");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("error_msg_local", "Internal error. Please try again.");
            console.log("3");
            // 3 gets logged when it should have been 1
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the question

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan "How can I make sure response.charAt(0) == "P" returns true ?"

Comment: is that a typo since you have commented charAt(0)

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yup. Typo.

Answer (score 4):

```
response.charAt[0]
```

That treats that `charAt` as an array. Note the diff between `()` and `[]`.

You should use parenthesis to use charAt . function

```
response.charAt(0)
```

Comment: Typo indeed. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in the comment, it should be **[`.charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)**

Change

**From**

```
if (response.charAt[0] === "P")
```

**To**

```
if (response.charAt(0) === "P")
```